# NGINX Alias path based on regex

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to add a new location block with an alias directive that are based on a dynamic URI to access different APIs. Right now I can do this manually adding each location block but was wondering if it could be mapped by using REGEX.

The problem is that it's returning a 404 error. I'm running a laravel sub app in a different folder on my server.

Any clues?

**

**WORKING MANUALLY**

```
location /api/product {
    alias /path/to/api/product/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite /api/product/(.*)$ /api/product/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

**ERROR 404 / No input file specified**

```
location ~ /api/(.*) {
    alias /path/to/api/$1/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite /api/(.*)/(.*)$ /api/$1/index.php?/$2 last;
}
```

**MORE TESTS**

A

`URL: app.tdl/api/tweets`

`Result: 'Index of /api/tweets/'`

`Output of $request_filename: /home/vagrant/code/Gateway/modules/tweets/app`

```
location /api/tweets {
  alias /home/vagrant/code/Gateway/modules/tweets/app;
  autoindex on;
}
```

B

`URL: app.tdl/api/tweets`

`Result: Nginx's 404`

`Output of $apiName: tweets`

`Output of $request_filename: /home/vagrant/code/Gateway/modules/tweets/app`

```
location ~ "/api/(?<apiName>[^/]+)" {
  alias "/home/vagrant/code/Gateway/modules/$apiName/app" ;
  autoindex on;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`alias` inside a *regular expression* `location` requires the full path to the file to be captured. See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Also, your existing capture is too greedy.

You may encounter problems using `try_files` with `alias` due to [this long standing issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97), you may want to replace it with an `if` block.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/api/(?<product>[^/]+)/(?<filename>.*)$ {
    alias /path/to/api/$product/public/$filename;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { 
        rewrite ^ /api/$product/index.php?/$filename last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        ...
    }
}
```

*Regular expression* `location` blocks are evaluated in order. This block needs to be placed above any conflicting *regular expression* `location` block, such as another `location ~ \.php$` block at the `server` block level.

The second `if` block is to avoid [passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. That makes sense and I think it should work but still getting the "no input file specified" message. Perhaps the rewrite rule could be missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure if the `rewrite` statement is correct - where is `index.php`? Inside the `public` directory or above it?

Comment: Each API has it's own /absolute/path/to/apiName/public/index.php (Laravel APPs).

Comment: I have checked and the $product and $filename works as expected. The rewrite statement should be the responsable for the 404. I've tried this one: `rewrite /api/$product/$filename /api/$product/index.php?/$filename last;`

Comment: Sorry, I confused myself. The `/public/` should not appear in the rewritten URI. The first parameter to the `rewrite` statement needs to be a regular expression, and I use `^` as it will match anything. In the above, the URI `/api/<product>/index.php` will be searched for in `/path/to/api/<product>/public/index.php`.

Comment: Hell, didn't work! I've tried to send a GET via PostMan to `http://gateway.local/api/products/last/3` and returned the `/home/vagrant/code/Gateway/modules/products/public/last/3`. Looks the IF is missing something...